# Add 20% to values multiple times in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, keyup

I am trying to add 20% to a span class on KeyUp of a field on the same row. I am stuck adding the 20% and I also don't think the rows are being picked up individually. I have the following:

jQuery code:

```
$(".account-form .price input[type='text']").on('keyup',function(){
        $(".account-form .price").each(function(){
            var value = $(this).find("input[type='text']").val();
        });
        $(".vatPrice").html(value);
    });
```

The html

```
<ul>
    <li class="price"><label><span>Price row 1</span><input value="20.00" type="text" name="price1"><span class="vatPrice">£0.00</span></label></li>
    <li class="price"><label><span>Price row 2</span><input value="40.00" type="text" name="price2"><span class="vatPrice">£0.00</span></label></li>
    <li class="price"><label><span>Price row 3</span><input value="80.00" type="text" name="price3"><span class="vatPrice">£0.00</span></label></li>
    <li class="price"><label><span>Price row 4</span><input value="120.00" type="text" name="price4"><span class="vatPrice">£0.00</span></label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: would be great if you can create a fiddle..

Comment: what is you want in OUTOUT show

Comment: Why does every other JavaScript question on this site have someone asking for "a fiddle"?

Comment: @BlueSkies, once you have a fiddle, the people answering can amend the original fiddle to fix it and save their version...also, the changed version can be tested at the same time.

Comment: @christiandev: If someone wants one, they can make one for themselves. It's not like the code isn't sitting right there.

Comment: @BlueSkies, I guess the object would be to supply as much information as possible in the question, and a fiddle adds additional assistance.

Comment: @christiandev: I would agree, except that all the information needed is already in the question. If an answerer needs assistance, then the answerer should provide it or simply not answer. It isn't like the question is about some odd behavior being experienced that's difficult to explain. It's just a simple *get value, add percentage, insert new value* problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$(".account-form .price input[type='text']").on('keyup', function () {
    var value = parseFloat(this.value) || 0;
    $(this).next(".vatPrice").html('£' + (value * 1.2).toFixed(2));
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TNJ33/)

Comment: Works Great on the initial value but after the '.' it doesnt so for example 1.99 it doesn't pick up the .99 ?

Comment: @neoszion use `parseFloat()`

Comment: Works great should of refreshed I was looking up toFixed :). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(".account-form .price input[type='text']").on('keyup',function(){           
   var value = (parseFloat($(this).val()) * 20) /100;           
   $(this).next('span').text('$' + ((isNaN(value)) ? 0 : value).toFixed(2));
 });
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TNJ33/3/)